# Reverse for 'edit-item' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/edit\\-item/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, slug

Can you please help me to find out the problem. Previously, the functions for editing and deleting the item are work. But, currently it shows me errors and I cannot find out the reason why this error happened suddenly. Can you guys please help me. I will be very appreciated.

**html**

```
{% for object in furniture %}
<tr class="clickable-tr" href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">
    <td>{{ object.furnitureId }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.furnitureName }}</td>
    <td>{{ object.categoryId.categoryName }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ object.stock }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href="{{ object.slug }}">
            <i class='material-icons' style="color: brown;">delete</i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Furniture(models.Model):
  furnitureId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
  furnitureName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  unitPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
  categoryId = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("administration:edit-item", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })

def delete_item_url(self):
    return reverse("administration:delete-item", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'administration'

urlpatterns = [
   path('products/',views.prodManagement,name='dashboard'),
   path('add-item/',views.addProduct,name='add-item'),
   path('edit-item/<slug>/',views.editProduct, name='edit-item'),
   path('delete-item/<slug>/',views.deleteItem, name='delete-item'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def prodManagement(request):
  context = {
    'furniture':Furniture.objects.all(),
    'category':Category.objects.all()
  }
  return render(request, 'admin/prod_management.html', context)

def editProduct(request, fid):
  item = get_object_or_404(Furniture, slug=fid)
  category = Category.objects.all()

  context = {
    'object':item, 
    'category':category
  }

  return render(request, 'admin/item.html', context)

def deleteItem(request, slug):
  print('here')
  item = get_object_or_404(Furniture, slug=slug)
  item.delete()

  messages.success(request, 'Item is deleted.')
  return redirect('administration:dashboard')
```

**Furniture Table**
[image: Furniture Table in MYSQL]

**The error**
[image: the error message]

Comment: Looks like `slug` field is not set for `Furniture` model

Comment: @Adithya I did set the slug for the model and the slug is work on my another application. I updated the post with furniture table record. please check.

Comment: You just need to provide the same name of the url parameter to the function. Instead of `def editProduct(request, fid):` replace **fid by slug** like this `def editProduct(request, slug):`